# Loop through php array content returning content to screen

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array that look like this($myArray)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 322 [Number] => 1 [Date] => 3117-01-41 [example] => Hello  ) 
[1] => Array ( [ID] => 123 [Number] => 49 [Date] => 1717-05-21 [example] => Hi )
[2] => Array ( [ID] => 007A [Number] => 42 [Date] => 2005-11-24 [example] => Some Text  )
[3] => Array ( [ID] => 999AAA [Number] => 492 [Date] => 3117-01-21 [example] => Text Test Text  )))
```

In my page i am using a function which returns content($content) and that content is displayed onto the web browser. No echoing or printing just returning the content variable which is constantly being appended to.

I deally i want to loop through my array and print the values from a certain field to the screen for example

```
while(//not sure what goes here){
  $content .= '<p>'.$someVariable["Number"].'</p>';
  $content .= '<p>'.$someVariable["example"].'</p>';
  $content .= '<p>'.$someVariable["date"].'</p>';
}
```

Im not sure if the while loop is the best way to achieve the desired result. Also using fetch_array is not an option i can use because it breaks previous code.

Comment: you can use `foreach`. But this type of question should be ask on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$yourArray = array ( 
array (
    'ID' => 322,
    'Number' => 1,
    'Date' => '3117-01-41',
    'example' => 'Hello'
), 
array (
    'ID' => 123,
    'Number' => 49,
    'Date' => '1717-05-21',
    'example' => 'Hi'
),
array (
    'ID' => '007A',
    'Number' => 42, 
    'Date' => '2005-11-24',
    'example' => 'Some Text'
),
array (
    'ID' => '999AAA',
    'Number' => 492,
    'Date' => '3117-01-21',
    'example' => 'Text Test Text'
)

);
?>
```

print whole array:

```
<?php print_r($yourArray); ?>
```

print certain levels of array:

```
<?php print_r($yourArray[2]); ?>
```

print certain element of array:

```
print_r($yourArray[2]['Date']);
```

print array level by level:

```
<?php
for($index=0; $index < count($yourArray); $index++){
    echo $yourArray[$index]['ID'].'<br>';
    echo $yourArray[$index]['Number'].'<br>';
    echo $yourArray[$index]['Date'].'<br>';
    echo $yourArray[$index]['example'].'<br>';
};
?>
```

Comment: printing to the screen is not an option, i'm appending to a variable which will be returned. Also i'm getting an index error when trying your last solution

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: ID

Comment: Copy the array above in the top box.

You can also echo values like:
    echo $yourArray[2]['ID'];
    echo $yourArray[2]['Number'];
    echo $yourArray[2]['Date'];
    echo $yourArray[2]['example'];

Comment: My original array is being created dynamically so i can not hard code new array format. is there a way to do so, because i am still getting the Undefined index error.

Answer (score 0):

This helps?

```
<?php

$yourArray = array (
    array (
        'ID' => 322,
        'Number' => 1,
        'Date' => '3117-01-41',
        'example' => 'Hello'
    ),
    array (
        'ID' => 123,
        'Address' => '1283 street, 576',
        'Date' => '1717-05-21',
        'country' => 'Canada'
    ),
    array (
        'ID' => '007A',
        'Number' => 42,
        'Date' => '2005-11-24',
        'example' => 'Some Text'
    ),
    array (
        'ID' => '999AAA',
        'Number' => 492,
        'Date' => '3117-01-21',
        'example' => array(
            'subID' => 45,
            'subAlias' => 'teste sub item'
        )
    )
);

$output = "";

function walkerFunction($item, $key) {
    global $output;
    $output .= $key . "->" . $item . PHP_EOL;
}

array_walk_recursive($yourArray, "walkerFunction");

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are seeking this:

```
$yourArray = array ( 
array (
    'ID' => 322,
    'Number' => 1,
    'Date' => '3117-01-41',
    'example' => 'Hello'
), 
array (
    'ID' => 123,
    'Number' => 49,
    'Date' => '1717-05-21',
    'example' => 'Hi'
),
array (
    'ID' => '007A',
    'Number' => 42, 
    'Date' => '2005-11-24',
    'example' => 'Some Text'
),
array (
    'ID' => '999AAA',
    'Number' => 492,
    'Date' => '3117-01-21',
    'example' => 'Text Test Text'
)

);


$content = '';
foreach($yourArray as $key => $value):

    $content .= '<p>'.$value["Number"].'</p>';
    $content .= '<p>'.$value["example"].'</p>';
    $content .= '<p>'.$value["Date"].'</p>';

endforeach;

print $content;
```